# Set Texture2D to "None" when default is something else

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data)
{
     Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
}
```

I have this method (and an exit method) set on every UI in my game. However, when I set it to null, it goes to the DEFAULT cursor. Now with Unity, I had already gone to project settings and set a custom cursor for Users to start with. However, when users go on to a UI, I want the cursor Texture2D to be "None", and setting it to null only sets it to the custom cursor I started with.

I understand that I can do a "void Start()" and simply set the Cursor to my custom one, and set my default cursor to "None", but since this script is running on every UI in my game, it just makes more sense to have my default set to the custom one and use c# to set it to "None" in certain circumstances.

Comment: By "I want the cursor Texture2D to be None", do you mean that you want the Cursor to be invisible?

Comment: No I want it to be the ultimate default: the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

What you want to do is not possible.

You will need to set the DefaultCursor in the Player Settings to None and then set the cursor explicitly when you want to use your custom cursor, thus allowing SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto) to reference the system pointer cursor.

It would probably be worthwhile creating a CursorManager script and accessing that from any UI elements that need to update the cursor.  In that script you could write a method such as:

```
public Texture2D GetCursor(string aCursor) {
    switch (aCursor) {
        case "none":
            return null;
        case "custompointer":
            return ...
        // Rest of implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Then, give your UI elements a reference to that script and call the method where needed.

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data)
{
    Cursor.SetCursor(CursorManager.GetCursor("none"), Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (DOES NOT WORK):**

*The approach below does not work because whilst you can set PlayerSettings.defaultCursor via code it can not be updated or changed at runtime.  It will set the defaultCursor at build time.*

On OnPointerEnter methods where you wish to use the default system Cursor, you will need to precede your current SetCursor call with a PlayerSettings.defaultCursor assignment.  I haven't tested this but the following should work.

```
PlayerSettings.defaultCursor = null;
Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
```

And then, set the PlayerSettings.defaultCursor to your custom default cursor Texture2D on the OnPointerExit method.

Comment: All good. I had an experiment myself and what you want to do is not possible.  The PlayerSettings can be configured (via the editor or code) but they can't be updated after the game is built.  Once you override the default cursor, then you can't access the system cursor - the override replaces it.  I can update my answer with a method to fix that problem, but I think it will be the very approach that you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with HumanWrites. When you set default cursor in Player Settings menu, you are overriding the Unity None Cursor and actually after build it does not exist.
If I'm going to use a custom default cursor and use unity none cursor as UI focused cursor, I would setCursor in MainController or once in any of UIs. Like this:

```
[SerializeField]
private Texture2D cursorTexture;
private static bool defaultCursorNotSet = true;

private void Awake()
{
    if (defaultCursorNotSet)
    {
        defaultCursorNotSet = false;
        SetCustomCursor();
    }
}

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data)
{
    SetNoneCursor();
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData data)
{
    SetCustomCursor();
}

private void SetNoneCursor()
{
    Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
}

private void SetCustomCursor()
{
    Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
}
```

Even if you could load the customTuxture in a static method, you could do so:

```
public class CursorHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private static Texture2D cursorTexture;

    static CursorHandler()
    {
        cursorTexture = ...
        SetCustomCursor();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data)
    {
        SetNoneCursor();
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData data)
    {
        SetCustomCursor();
    }

    private static void SetNoneCursor()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(null, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
    }

    private static void SetCustomCursor()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.Auto);
    }
}
```